# Linux shell emailing - set sender address using "mail" command

Tags: linux, shell

I am using the "mail" command in Linux shell to send an email when programmatically prompted to do so. I am using

```
mail -s 'subject' recipient@theirhost.com <<< 'Email body'
```

to send it at present, but this does not include a sender address. Instead, the system uses the account name as the sender address. I've seen the claim that "-aFrom:myname@myhost.com" should work, but -a is being interpreted as an attachment attempt, not a header change. This results in the error: "From:Mynamemyname@myhost.com: No such file or directory". I've also seen a claim that this works:

```
-r "from@fromserver.com"
```

But the OS doesn't even know what that means, in my case.

Is there a way to make this work without additional software? I don't need a from name, but a from address would be very helpful.

Note: let's consider ssmtp, mutt, and other such add-on software unavailable. Attempting to install and use such software would be problematic.

Thank you!

**Edit 1**: I'm not certain how to check what version of "mail" I have. With some difficulty, I got it to spit out the usage, which is as follows.

```
-T FILE -u USER -h hops -r address -s SUBJECT -a FILE -q FILE -f FILE -A ACCOUNT -b USERS -c USERS -S OPTION users
```

Comment: `mailx -r from_me@server.com -s ...` works

Comment: There are several different versions of `mail` out there, which support different command line options.  Can you determine which one is installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got it. "-r" can actually work.
I successfully used:

```
echo "This is the message body" | mail -s "This is the Subject" -r "FromName<fromAddress@example.com>" recipientName@example.com
```

It looks like karakfa was onto something also, as I do have mailx available to me also, but it looks like I won't be needing that for this use case.

Thank you!